# Configure single endpoint for all WCF services offerend in project?

Tags: c#, wcf

In my WCF project, I have two services Products and Customers. Both these services have separate interface and implementation .cs files. In App.Config I could see the below,

```
      <service name="DemoProj.Services.ProductService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="DemoProj.Services.Interfaces.IProductService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/DemoProj/Service/ProductService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
  <service name="DemoProj.Services.CustomerService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="DemoProj.Services.Interfaces.ICustomerService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/DemoProj/Service/CustomerService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

When the client consumes this WCF service, it will require both Products and Customers service.

My question is, I will have many more services and the App.config is going to be big with lots of endpoints. In my current scenario, I will need only one contract, binding, address for all my services like Products, Customers and so on. I need to only configure one endpoint that is shared by all the services I expose to my client.

I understand, it is by WCF design where it is more flexible to have different configurations for different services offered. But in my case i don't require like that. I want to make my App.config simple with only one endpoint.

Comment: The purpose of having different interfaces is to maintain easily. And so the implementations of interfaces..

Comment: Well you can always do a 'Facade' - Make one Service that Implements all the Individual Interfaces. The OperationContracts merely call the actual Products or Customer etc operations. Then configure this single service as the endpoint. However - this is really bad design.